# Emirates checked-in luggage and carry-on bag rules/dimensions

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, emirates

I phoned call Emirates Airlines to ask about the luggage allowance and I visited their websites. I'm travelling from (BAH to AKL), Emirates agent informed me that I can carry a checked in luggage that's less or equal to **300** in total dimension, that is:

Total dimension = length + width + height <= 300

Because I'm travelling with **Economy Flex** ticket, the weight of the checked-in luggage should not exceed 30 kg for the checked in luggage or additional fees will be charged. *Did I get this right?*

**Carry-on bag:**

According to Emirates website: [Baggage allowance and rules](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/baggages/baggage_calculator_result.aspx?departure=bah&arrival=akl&class=yf&tier=sn&h=ca688186d57515d3731e524f7c2ce26eee1f33) and as I understand the carry-on bag should be within the range of the following dimensions according to the picture:

Height: 56cm  ~ 22"
Width:  36cm  ~ 14"
Depth:  23cm  ~  9 "

*So the total dimension of the handbag/carry-on bag should be less than or equal to: 56 + 36 + 23 = **115cm**

**Do 56cm, 36cm, 23cm stand for height, width and depth respectively? I read this at the beginning as if they meant: Length x Width x Height and this is where the confusion occurred, but after searching the web I found this picture with close dimensions to the ones mentioned in emirates website which reversed my mind set:

[image: www.en.ch.com]

What exactly are the precise rules for checked-in luggage and carry-on-bag in the United Arab Emirates ?

Comment: You don't need to stress about this. I'm sure you don't need us to check your arithmetic or your abililty to read the Emirates website.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to know you already have written in your answer - I think you may just be anxious about your trip which is normal, even for some seasoned travelers.

Here are some rules that apply to almost all airlines (with the exception of low cost carriers):

1. There is maximum limit that a bag can weigh before it requires special handling, this is due to the way the many miles of belts that ferry your luggage from the check-in desk to the airplane work. You can find out exactly what this limit is, by looking at the limit of the first class baggage; for Emirates this is **50 KG**. This is the **hard limit on how much a specific piece can weigh, no matter what class you are traveling on**.
2. The other limit is the number of items you can take; well to be fair there is no limit. The limit is on the number of items you can check-in *for free*; you can always pay to carry extra pieces of luggage (no matter what class you travel on).
3. The physical size of the luggage. There are two different sizes. The carry-on size (and weight) and the checked luggage size (and weight - as detailed above).

Now, each class of travel gets a different allowance for free luggage:

1. Economy gets 30 KG for free per bag, and two bags for free. You can pay to either:

   a. Carry more *per bag* up to a limit of 50 KG. So if your one piece of luggage is 45 KG, you have to pay the 15 KG difference from your free allowance.

   b. Carry extra bags, above your free allowance of 2. So if you want to check-in a third bag, you will pay the extra amount to check in an additional bag. If the bag weighs more than 30 KG, you'll pay the difference in weight (as detailed above).

   c. No matter what, you cannot check-in a single piece of luggage that weighs more than 50 KG.
2. Business class gets two bags, but 40 KG each.
3. First class gets two bags, but 50 KG each.

That's all there is to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Really, there is not much to say about your question since you already have all the official info.*

The only thing I can clarify is that the carry-on limit has a limit on each dimension. You cannot take an item which exceeds the the height, for example, even if it is less than the width limit. Some airlines use a linear measure for carry-on too but mostly you have a limit per dimension to ensure the carry-on fits in the overhead bin. These dimensions officially include wheels and handles but there is usually some leeway.

Another note is that you can choose which side is the height, which is the width and depth. Just because the opening is on one side, that does not mean that the height must be measured from that side. There are different types and shapes of bags and suitcases and the importance is that they fit without defined boundaries. Many airports have a metal frame of the right size, so that people can measure their luggage. If it fits entirely within the frame, no matter which way you oriented the item, then it is allowed as carry-on.